# Is there an easier way to truncate a string with PHP regex?

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
Security/Flow_Setup/Steady_State/Verification
```

I only need the first two levels (e.g. **Security/Flow_Setup**) Is there an easier way to get this.  Currently I explode the string into an array using: '/' as a delimiter and then piece together elements 0 and 1.

This works but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you seen the `dirname()` function? It does pretty much what you're looking for without any messy regex nonsense. (if you call it twice, in your case)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can get too much more elegant/short than this if you only need the first two pieces:

```
list($var1, $var2) = explode('/', $str);
```

Regex is totally unnecessary here.

Someone mentioned [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586011/is-there-an-easier-way-to-truncate-a-string-with-php-regex/10586064#comment13713538_10586011), which I thought was a clever and probably appropriate idea, and very short and readable (and gets you the string you need instead of two separate parts like the code above):

```
$str = 'Security/Flow_Setup/Steady_State/Verification';

echo dirname(dirname($str));

// Output: Security/Flow_Setup
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you do everything ok. You can try it this way if you like:

```
$str = "Security/Flow_Setup/Steady_State/Verification";
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '/', strpos($str, '/') + 1));
```

(No arrays involved, should be a little bit faster)

Answer (score 2):

not a typical usage nor a string function, but since your string is effectively a path, maybe this would suffice...

```
dirname(dirname('Security/Flow_Setup/Steady_State/Verification'));
```

Comment: Best answer, IMO. It does seem awkward to use dirname on strings that aren't really paths, but who know - maybe it is one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest and most efficient one-liner I can come up with:

```
$firstTwoParts = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $str, 3), 0, 2));
```

This could be wrapped into a function that let's you control how many parts you want:

```
function first_n_parts ($str, $n, $delimiter = '/') {
  return ($n = (int) $n) ? implode($delimiter, array_slice(explode($delimiter, $str, $n + 1), 0, $n)) : '';
}
```

...so you can do:

```
echo first_n_parts($str, 1); // Security
echo first_n_parts($str, 2); // Security/Flow_Setup
echo first_n_parts($str, 3); // Security/Flow_Setup/Steady_State
```

Answer (score 0):

this regex should do it

```
'/^([a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)?/'
```